# How to disclose parental name change on form DS-11

Tags: passports, paperwork, us-citizens, applications

According to the current* [DS-11 US Passport Application](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds11.pdf), on Page 2, under **10. Parental Information**, the applicant is asked for the following two pieces of information about each parent:

- Mother/Father/Parent - First & Middle Name
- Last Name (at Parent's Birth)

Notably, the first field (First & Middle Name) does *not* have the "at Parent's Birth" qualification.

What names should be listed if the parent in question has *legally* changed their name? From a literal reading of the fields above, the form is asking for the *current* first and middle name of the parent but the *birth* last name. For example, if my father was born as John-Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt but legally changed his name to Thor Hammerman Odinson before I was born, I would be expected to report his name on the form as Thor Hammerman Schmidt, but this seems absurd, as this would represent *a name he has never used* - his birth certificate presumably has John-Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt, and my birth certificate would list my father as Thor Hammerman Odinson. Am I reading too much into the form, and they intended to imply that I should put down the entire name, first, middle, and last, as it was at the parent's birth?

*Note: I am aware that the document above has an OMB Expiration Date of August 31, 2019. Current [guidance](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/forms.html) from the US Department of State is to continue using this form for the time being.

This question has nothing to do with how to falsify or get away with falsifying a US passport application. Rather, it is about how to *honestly* answer the questions at the required level of detail without inadvertently falsifying it or otherwise causing myself or the government a headache.

Comment: My bureaucratic instincts tell me that you ought to use all names as they were at birth, but I can't find any official information either way. This situation is actually very rare.

Comment: I doubt it would be *that* rare. If I had kids, they would have this exact problem filling out this form. When it comes to government forms like this, though, unless explicit guidance exists, I take the instructions literally and would fill out first/middle as it is today, and last name as it was at birth.

Comment: The top of the form has a phone number and email address to reach the State Department for information and questions.  I would suggest asking them instead of relying on guesses from the Internet.  If you do, you could post an answer here saying what you learned.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Did your kids' parents also change their first and middle names? Consider why the State Department wants this information. They are going to go look for a birth record. In that case, they won't find it. The passport application will be delayed and possibly refused.

Comment: @MichaelHampton My point was more that it's not overly unusual. Consider, if you will, a child adopted soon after birth whose entire name is changed. We can probably all agree that it is a poorly conceived of set of questions, but not following its instructions is usually not the solution. Nate is probably correct in that the appropriate action would be to reach out for additional guidance from an official source.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'll agree with contacting an official source. It appears that the things I'd like to quote in support of this are classified, or at least inaccessible without a FOIA request, so I'm not going to write an answer, but I will say that I still expect the answer to be to use the parent's full names as they were at birth.

Comment: I would try asking the state department.  I would use the example of Gerald Rudolph Ford, Jr., who was born in 1913 as Leslie Lynch King, Jr., and legally changed his name in 1935.  (He had apparently been using the name Gerald Rudolff Ford, Jr., since 1916 when his mother married his stepfather, however, with a different spelling of the middle name.)

Comment: It's such a minor detail that I would input the names precisely as asked, even if it doesn't make sense.